# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to '...''

Tags: heroku

this is my server folder: https://github.com/Yokubjon-J/react-chat-testSuite/tree/master/server. whenever i run "git push heroku master" i am getting the error below:

```
Total 866 (delta 199), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-first-react-chat-app.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/my-first-react-chat-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-first-react-chat-app.git'
```

I have browsed through several stackoverflow answers to no avail.
Any suggestions?
I set buildpacks, typed "web: node index.js" in procfile, but none of it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `cd ..` and then `git subtree push --prefix server heroku master`. this way the problem was solved. For reference: https://dev.to/stlnick/how-to-deploy-a-full-stack-mern-app-with-heroku-netlify-ncb

Answer (score 1):

The error says "No default language could be detected for this app.

Try:

heroku buildpacks:set heroku/the-programming-language  OR

heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/the-programming-language

refer-https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks